# How to find the error on web2py and GAE SDK when I got Internal error - Ticket issued: unknow

Tags: python, google-app-engine, web2py

I'm working with Web2py and Google App Engine SDK.
I have an action that works using the WSGI version, but fails when running on SDK.

Inside this action, there are no imports specific from GAE libraries... but I can't figure out what is wrong cause I only got the message:

Internal error
Ticket issued: unknown

And there is no ticket showing the error.

How can I debug web2py when working with GAE and specifically in this case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to read the logs on GAE dashboard to figure out the Python exception it is throwing

Comment: Thank you! It works on remote App Engine... but is there any logs like this on App Engine SDK?